# Parse Server header

Tags: reactjs, api, parse-server

How can I provide these in headers? I'm using `Parse.Cloud.run('endpoint-here', request)` to get the response from the API. I'm using ReactJS for this app.

```
X-Parse-Application-Id: {{appid}}
X-Parse-Master-Key: {{masterkey}}
X-Parse-session-token: {{session}}
X-Parse-Javascript-Key: {{session}}
```

Sample

```
 const formUpdateAPI = Parse.Cloud.run('endpoint-for-update', request);

 formUpdateAPI
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to initialize the SDK with:

```js
Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER'
```

Then the SDK will send the headers automatically for all your requests.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I put this on the app? What's the ideal or correct way to implement this?

Comment: I'd add that in app.js